# Activerecord adds additional conditions in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

For example I am doing something like this:

```
PlatformInformer.where(1)
```

and result query via

```
PlatformInformer.where(1).to_sql
```

is

```
SELECT `platform_informers`.* FROM `platform_informers`  WHERE `platform_informers`.`platform` = 'android' AND `platform_informers`.`email` = 'voldemar@klops.ru' AND (1)
```

I didn't ask to add email and platform fields in where clause!

This problem causes when I am executing code inside PlatforInformer model methods. Default scope is doesn't set. What is the root of evil?

Rails 3.2.13

**UPDATE**:

```
class PlatformInformer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasUniqueGenerator

  attr_accessible :email, :platform,:secret_code,:activated,:invitation_sent

  before_create :init_secret_code

  PLATFORMS = %w(windows macos android ios)

  def self.PLATFORMS
    PLATFORMS
  end

  validates :platform, :presence => true,:inclusion => { :in =>PLATFORMS }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true

  validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :platform

  scope :confirmed, Proc.new { where(:activated => true) }

  def several_platforms?
    PlatformInformer.confirmed.find_all_by_email(self.email).count > 0
  end

  def send_confirmation
    if already_subscribed?
      activate!
    else
      PlatformInformerMailer.inform_me(self.id).deliver
    end
  end

  def activate!
    PlatformInformer.where(:email=>self.email).update_all(:activated=>true)
  end


  private
  def init_secret_code
    gen_unique_code :secret_code, 16
  end

  def already_subscribed?
    PlatformInformer.confirmed.where(email: self.email).any?
  end

end
```

Comment: could you post your PlatformInformer model?

Comment: I have updated problem description.

Comment: Have you tried `PlatformInformer.unscoped.where(1).to_sql` ? May be the default scope is still set somewhere via metaprogramming... what is in the `HasUniqueGenerator` module? Also you can search the project folder for `PlatformInformer` and check all places where it's present.

Comment: problem was in using method first_or_create, that creates virtual scope with two params: email and platform. Thanks for answers, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in using first_or_create method, that created virtual scope with email and platform attributes.